# Encountered AttributeError: 'Permission' object has no attribute '_revisions' after upgrading Wagtail from 2.6.2 to 4.0.1

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I encountered the following error when accessing Pages in Wagtail Admin:

File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\models_*init*_.py", line 983, in revisions
return self.specific_deferred._revisions
AttributeError: 'Permission' object has no attribute '_revisions'

It seems to be some conflicts in the wagtail model that caused the error, and it only occured after I upgrade wagtail from ver. 2.6.1 to 4.0.1.

Thanks

Comment: If it's retrieving a Permission object at that point, that's an indication that the ContentType records in the database have become mixed up. Did you do any sort of dumping/restoring of the database (e.g. with the ./manage.py dumpdata / loaddata commands) as part of the upgrade process? That can lead to issues like this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I don't think I have conducted any dumping of the database

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem ? i'm getting almost the same here  : 'Embed' object has no attribute '_revisions'

Comment: I got a similar error when updating from 4.0 to 4.1.1. I did indeed use fixtures with the loaddata command. How do I fix this?